# git, push --mirror, restore deleted branches

Tags: git, github, fork

I made private fork of the public repo on GitHub using this guide
https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository

```
git clone --mirror <path-to-some-public-repo>
cd ./some-public-repo.git
git remote rm origin
git remote add upstream <path-to-some-public-repo>
git remote add privatefork <path-to-your-private-fork>
git push --mirror privatefork
```

I made some work, created my own branch, pushed branch to private fork. Then I fetched updates from upstream to my privatefork

```
git fetch -p upstream
git push --mirror privatefork
```

My new branch was deleted during update. Commits still in repo, but branch has been deleted.
Of course I could create branch again, but it's a wrong way.

What should I do to update private fork and keep new branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess, since you did not publish your new branch to the "upstream" the invoked [`git fetch -p`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch):

> "[r]emove[s after fetching] any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote."
>   *- git-fetch(1) Manual Page*

With other words you may push and change as much as you want (on "privatefork") with every `fetch -p` from **upstream** you're going to remove your changes.

Besides of that: working with `--mirror` and `--prune` - the whole help-article on GitHub - is mentioned to create 1:1-copies/backups of repositories. If you plan to work with the repository, leave the options away and do "normal" forking.

Comment: What do you mean "normal forking"? Just `git clone <pulic-repo>`, `git push <private-fork>`. And to update - `git fetch upstream`, `git push <private-fork>`. Right? This will work fine?

Comment: Yes, try the commands without options as long as you don't have a substantiated reason to use (and understand) them. Avoid the use of `--force/-f` and other options which may be irreversible (the man-files point that out).